# Ionic React Component only showing when clicking button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and React and want to build a mobile App. The App's UI structure is not new, I have a main screen that acts like a feed and shows data fetched from Firebase. The issue is that upon opening the page, the component responsible of showing the data `<Requests/>` is not rendered.
In order to do so, I have to click on a button - the first `<IonFabButton>` inside `<IonFabList>` to reveal the modal - and it does not make any sense to me. Thanks.

```
return (
<IonPage>
  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle>Requêtes de Livraison</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>
  <IonContent>
  <Requests requests={deliveryRequests} />
    <IonModal isOpen={showModal}>
      <h2>Créer une nouvelle requête de livraison</h2>
      <IonInput value={newDeliveryRequestTitle} placeholder="Entrer un titre..." onIonChange={e => setNewDeliveryRequestTitle(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
      <IonInput value={newDeliveryRequestDescription} placeholder="Entrer une description..." onIonChange={e => setNewDeliveryRequestDescription(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
      <IonButton onClick={() => { setShowModal(false); }}>Fermer</IonButton>
      <IonButton onClick={() => {
        createNewDeliveryRequest({
          title: newDeliveryRequestTitle,
          description: newDeliveryRequestDescription,
          followers: 0
        }); setShowModal(false);
      }}>Créer</IonButton>
    </IonModal>
    <IonFab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
      <IonFabButton><IonIcon icon={chevronUpCircleOutline} /></IonFabButton>
      <IonFabList side="top">
        <IonFabButton onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}><IonIcon icon={addCircleOutline} /></IonFabButton>
        <IonFabButton><IonIcon icon={navigateCircleOutline} /></IonFabButton>
      </IonFabList>
    </IonFab>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

);

Comment: Which button..?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my question.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with useEffect(). According to the React Documentation, useEffect() runs after rendering, in my case, I only fetch the data after everything has been rendered, so I cannot see them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution to my problem was quite simple, a dumb mistake in a function was the cause:

```
    const fetchDeliveryRequests = () =>{
    let requests = Array<DeliveryRequest>();
    db.collection('delivery-requests').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let deliveryRequest: DeliveryRequest = {
          title: doc.data().title,
          description: doc.data().description,
          followers: doc.data().followers,
        };
        requests.push(deliveryRequest);
      });

    });
    setDeliveryRequests(requests); //It should not be here
  }
```

I changed it to:

```
const fetchDeliveryRequests = () =>{
let requests = Array<DeliveryRequest>();
db.collection('delivery-requests').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let deliveryRequest: DeliveryRequest = {
      title: doc.data().title,
      description: doc.data().description,
      followers: doc.data().followers,
    };
    requests.push(deliveryRequest);
  });
     setDeliveryRequests(requests); //New place
});
```

}

Explanation:
setDeliveryRequests() was called outside/after the get() method. It had no time to pass the data forward.